# Initial value for class instance variable in inheritance chain

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I want to save separate values for each class along with it's inherited classes, and want these values to be initially `[]`. So I thought of using instance class variables since they are not shared across inheritance chain:

```rb
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      @foos = []
    end

    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :foos
  end
end
```

which I include in other class, which have children classes

```rb
class Bar
  include Foo
end

class Baz < Bar
end

Bar.foos        # []
Baz.foos        # nil
```

So, my question is what is the best way to have the value of `Baz.foos` to be initially `[]` instead of `nil` dynamically without opening the children class?

I tried to use class variables instead of instance class variables but then all classes will share the same copy of the class variable `@@foos`

Thanks

Comment: `def foos ; @foos ||= [] ; end` maybe?

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan This worked Couldn't believe it was that easy. Feel free to answer it so I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the suggestion provided by @Stefan in comments is probably the way to go, it’s still possible with metaprogramming; one just needs to [handle inheritance](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited).

```rb
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval { @foos = [] }
    class << base
      attr_reader :foos
      def inherited(other)
        Foo.included(other)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

class Baz < Bar; end

Bar.foos #⇒ []
Baz.foos #⇒ []
```

Comment: Thanks,  @Aleksei , any idea how to use `inherited` inside `class_methods` block when using `ActiveSupport::Concern`'s included instead  of `self.included(base)....` ?

Comment: I have no idea about ActiveSupport, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway, you were very helpful